# Center aligning an element with firefox and 100% width

Tags: html, css, firefox

So Im trying to do a simple header where I have the text aligned central with a 2px border running underneath this.

The code I have works and should work perfectly on every other browser except firefox which is aligning the border right of the page as if the beginning of the border is aligned in the center. If I remove the text align center the border is placed perfectly but the text is aligned to the left obviously. Why is firefox doing this?

CSS:

```
  .my-title {
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 70px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;

}
.my-title:after {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 2px;
    background-color: #ffd500;
    content: "";
    width: 100%;

}
.align-center {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Html:

```
<div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <hgroup class="my-title align-center">
          <h1>Header</h1>
          <h2>Sub-Header</h2>
        </hgroup>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Don't use `<hgroup />` as it has been dropped from [HTML5 Specification.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/hgroup)

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realise, just been always using it, what would I use instead?

Comment: There is no current replacement for `<hgroup>` though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using property `left` solved the problem:

```
.my-title:after {
    left: 0;
}
```

<kbd>[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/XL8Rf/)</kbd>

Comment: You beauty! That solved the issue, much appreciated. Do you know why Firefox adds this? all other browsers were fine including ie strangely.

Answer (score 3):

since your pseudo element is in `position:absolute;` it has no width in the flow of your content and follows `text-align:center;` set on parent.( as absolute it has,  in the flow of content,  **0** for heigh and width).

3 possibilities:

1. add the rule : `left:0;` no matter what text-align on parent will be, it will be drawn from left coordonates.
2. add the rule : `display:block;` so it behaves like a block element and ill ignore the `text-align`, it will do a break line and will be drawn from `left` or `right` (follows the `direction/dir` of document).
3. keep it in the flow:

```
.my-title {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 70px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}
.my-title:after {
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #ffd500;
  content: "";
  width:100%;
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:bottom;
}
.align-center {
  text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@-moz-document url-prefix()
  {
  .my-title 
  {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 70px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;

  }

  .my-title:after 
  {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #ffd500;
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  }

  .align-center
  {
      text-align: center;
  }
  }
```